# What is the different between opencv-python library and cv2 library?

Tags: python, opencv, virtualenv, gpu

I am trying to use openCV. Normally, When I run command panel on desktop, I can see version of my openCV:

[image]

But when I couldn't import to my project. Normally, I was adding opencv-python library from interpreter but I builded cv2 library which version is 4.4.0 to use gpu. So I haven't got a opencv-python library at site-packages but I have cv2 file in site-packages. Unfortunately I couldn't import it to my project. How can I use this opencv version or file which name is cv2.cp37-win_amd64.pyd?

[image]

I can use all other libraries in site-packages. But when I couldn't add cv2 library. Here the a basic image read from file :

[image]

The interesting part of the problem is, all cv2 function cannot be found but program is working :D I am really confused.

Answer (score 9):

cv2 is the module import name for [opencv-python](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/), "Unofficial pre-built CPU-only OpenCV packages for Python". The traditional OpenCV has many complicated steps involving building the module from scratch, which is unnecessary. I would recommend remaining with the opencv-python library.

The IDE probably doesn't recognize the cv2 commands because you are using a 64 bit version of opencv-python on a 32 bit version of Python or vice-versa. I believe this can be resolved by uninstalling your current OpenCV installation using `pip uninstall opencv-python` and then reinstalling it with the correct version following the linked tutorial.

Sources / Additional Links:
Install Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z78zbnLlPUA

Comment: "an unnoficial CPU-only version of OpenCV" makes no sense. OpenCV officially has python bindings. they access most of the available functions, and that includes all the GPU support. the python package index has an "opencv-python" package that is built and maintained by a volunteer who is not affiliated with OpenCV. that has no impact on the python bindings themselves or the GPU support. the package is quite full-featured.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I might be mistaken, but the pypi package [description](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) states that opencv-python is CPU-only

Comment: touché. I didn't actually check what module I'm running that has hardware support.

Comment: GPU support is not provided on the PyPI `opencv-python` packages because not everyone has a CUDA-enabled video card and would thus limit the amount of people who could use the package.  GPU support for OpenCV currently only handles NVIDIA cards.  Granted, there is OpenCL support on OpenCV but it is very limited and still experimental.  Without even checking the description on the PyPI page, it makes sense to release with CPU-only.  Either way, nice link DapperDuck!

Comment: Thanks @rayryeng !